# Is there any java memory structures that will automatically page data to disk?

Tags: memcached, memory-management, out-of-memory, ehcache

Basically, I am caching a bunch of files in memory.  The problem is, if I get too many files cached into memory I can run out of memory.

Is there any sort of java memory structure that will automatically page part of itself to disk?

For example, I would like to set a 2 mb limit the size of the files in memory.  After that limit I would like some of the files to be written to disk.

Is there any library that does this sort of thing?

Grae

Answer (score 0):

‎"files in memory". Conventionally, in memory data is stored in some data structure like a HashMap or whatever, and referred to as a 'file' when its written to disc. You could code a data storage class which did this programmatically. I don't know of any library which did this. It would be pretty useful. In effect you would be implementing virtual memory.

This link will might help you :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html

Answer (score 0):

[EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) is general purpose caching library for Java. One of the option is to have disk-backed cache, which overflows to file system. Seems to be exactly what you need.